# Set to hold key value pairs in java

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am facing a problem where i need to store unique key value pairs in a set. As per my knowledge I can't have key value pairs in set so I am using a map and checking the entryset() values to confirm what I am about to insert doesn't already exist. If i check a pair (a,c) doesnt exist in map but there is (a,b) present, the insert of (a,c) updates the (a,b) entry and I am unable to save both the key value pairs. Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: Then don't store `b`, but basically `[b]`, aka. an array / list of values.

Comment: It won't be efficient as I need a count of all unique pairs in the end.

Comment: Don't come up with new requirements in the comments, include them in the question. And what does "efficient" mean? What is a unique pair in this context? You can always keep a counter or N counters alongside the map. What operations do you want to achieve with what "efficiency" / time complexity - and why, what is the expected input and output?

Comment: I understand, you can chose not to answer I will wait for someone else if it triggers you.

Comment: “*As per my knowledge I can't have key value pairs in set*”—your problem is probably best fixed by adjusting your knowledge. Why do you think you can’t have key value pairs in a set?

Comment: because "As per my knowledge"....

Comment: A `Set` can contain practically anything. So there should be a stronger reason than “as per my knowledge” for an assumption that a particular use case is impossible.

Comment: Not as experienced as most pros here, only used standard wrapper classes till now which java provides like Integer, Character etc. I guess that's what I needed help with. Be gentle on learners.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to be a language issue. Instead of “*As per my knowledge I can't have…*” you should have used something like “*I don’t know how to…*”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your custom pair class in case you have no dependency related to pair such as Spring, Guava,... Then you have to override equals and hashcode method to have a set contains elements you wanted:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public final class Pair<L, R> {

    private final L key;

    private final R value;

    private Pair(final L key, final R value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static <L, R> Pair<L, R> of(final L key, final R value) {
        return new Pair<>(key, value);
    }

    public L getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public R getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public boolean equals(@Nullable final Object object) {
        if (this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if (object == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.getClass() != object.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Pair<?, ?> other = (Pair) object;
        return Objects.equals(this.key, other.key) && Objects.equals(this.value, other.value);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.key, this.value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%s - %s)", this.key, this.value);
    }

}
```

Following is the result that I use with it that might meet your desired output:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final HashSet<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs = new HashSet<>();
        pairs.add(Pair.of(12, "Hello"));
        pairs.add(Pair.of(12, "Hi"));
        pairs.add(Pair.of(13, "Hello"));
        pairs.add(Pair.of(14, "Hello"));
        pairs.add(Pair.of(15, "Hello"));
        System.out.println(pairs); // => [(13 - Hello), (12 - Hello), (15 - Hello), (14 - Hello), (12 - Hi)]
    }
```

In case you don't want to create new class. You can use buildin class Entry from Map.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final HashSet<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> pairs = new HashSet<>();
    pairs.add(Map.entry(12, "Hello"));
    pairs.add(Map.entry(12, "Hi"));
    pairs.add(Map.entry(12, "Hi"));
    pairs.add(Map.entry(13, "Hello"));
    pairs.add(Map.entry(14, "Hello"));
    pairs.add(Map.entry(15, "Hello"));
    System.out.println(pairs);
    // [12=Hello, 13=Hello, 14=Hello, 15=Hello, 12=Hi]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for some inbuilt solution if Java provides any.

Comment: As fas as I know, this class is not available in Java builtin. Therefore, many utility dependencies out there have to create it. You can  see this class in Guava, Apache, Spring...

Comment: Sorry for the last comment. I found out that you can achieve the same thing with the builtin class Map.Entry. I edited my answer so you can see how it works.

Comment: With an up-to-date Java, you can simply use `public record Pair<L, R>(L key, R value) {}` to achieve the same. An alternative is to just use instances of [`SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html), which works even under Java 8.